# Quantlib convertible bond pricing typeerror with 'new_ConvertibleFixedCouponBond'

Tags: python, swig, quantlib

I am pricing a convertible bond using quantLib library in Python but I get error with `ql.new_ConvertibleFixedCouponBond`

My Code:

```
import QuantLib as ql

calculation_date = ql.Date(9,1,2004)
ql.Settings.instance().evaluationDate = calculation_date

redemption = 100.00
face_amount = 100.0
spot_price = 29.04
conversion_price = 26.0
conversion_ratio = 3.84615  # BBG quotes 38.4615; had to scale by a factor of 10

issue_date = ql.Date(15,3,2002)        
maturity_date = ql.Date(15,3,2022)

settlement_days = 2
calendar = ql.UnitedStates(ql.UnitedStates.GovernmentBond)
coupon = 0.0575
frequency = ql.Semiannual
tenor = ql.Period(frequency)

day_count = ql.Thirty360()
accrual_convention = ql.Unadjusted
payment_convention = ql.Unadjusted

call_dates = [ql.Date(20,3,2007)]
call_price = 100.0
put_dates = [ql.Date(20,3,2007), ql.Date(15,3,2012), ql.Date(15,3,2017)]
put_price = 100.0

# assumptions
dividend_yield = 0.02
credit_spread_rate = 0.03  
risk_free_rate = 0.04
volatility = 0.40

callability_schedule = ql.CallabilitySchedule()


for call_date in call_dates:
   callability_price  = ql.BondPrice(call_price, 
                                            ql.BondPrice.Clean)
   callability_schedule.append(ql.Callability(callability_price, 
                                       ql.Callability.Call,
                                       call_date)
                        )
    
for put_date in put_dates:
    puttability_price = ql.BondPrice(put_price, 
                                            ql.BondPrice.Clean)
    callability_schedule.append(ql.Callability(puttability_price,
                                               ql.Callability.Put,
                                               put_date))

dividend_schedule = ql.DividendSchedule() # No dividends
dividend_amount = dividend_yield*spot_price
next_dividend_date = ql.Date(1,12,2004)
dividend_amount = spot_price*dividend_yield
for i in range(4):
    date = calendar.advance(next_dividend_date, 1, ql.Years)
    dividend_schedule.append(
        ql.FixedDividend(dividend_amount, date)
    )

schedule = ql.Schedule(issue_date, maturity_date, tenor,
                       calendar, accrual_convention, accrual_convention,
                       ql.DateGeneration.Backward, False)

credit_spread_handle = ql.QuoteHandle(ql.SimpleQuote(credit_spread_rate))
exercise = ql.AmericanExercise(calculation_date, maturity_date)

convertible_bond = ql.ConvertibleFixedCouponBond(exercise,
                                                 conversion_ratio,
                                                 dividend_schedule,
                                                 callability_schedule, 
                                                 credit_spread_handle,
                                                 issue_date,
                                                 settlement_days,
                                                 [coupon],
                                                 day_count,
                                                 schedule,
                                                 redemption)
```

The error i get:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-4-b1df79b0869b> in <module>
     69 exercise = ql.AmericanExercise(calculation_date, maturity_date)
     70 
---> 71 convertible_bond = ql.ConvertibleFixedCouponBond(exercise,
     72                                                  conversion_ratio,
     73                                                  dividend_schedule,

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\QuantLib\QuantLib.py in __init__(self, *args)
  18679 
  18680     def __init__(self, *args):
> 18681         _QuantLib.ConvertibleFixedCouponBond_swiginit(self, _QuantLib.new_ConvertibleFixedCouponBond(*args))
  18682     __swig_destroy__ = _QuantLib.delete_ConvertibleFixedCouponBond
  18683 

TypeError: Wrong number or type of arguments for overloaded function 'new_ConvertibleFixedCouponBond'.
  Possible C/C++ prototypes are:
    ConvertibleFixedCouponBond::ConvertibleFixedCouponBond(ext::shared_ptr< Exercise > const &,Real,std::vector< ext::shared_ptr< Callability >,std::allocator< ext::shared_ptr< Callability > > > const &,Date const &,Integer,std::vector< Rate,std::allocator< Rate > > const &,DayCounter const &,Schedule const &,Real,Period const &,Calendar const &,BusinessDayConvention const,bool)
    ConvertibleFixedCouponBond::ConvertibleFixedCouponBond(ext::shared_ptr< Exercise > const &,Real,std::vector< ext::shared_ptr< Callability >,std::allocator< ext::shared_ptr< Callability > > > const &,Date const &,Integer,std::vector< Rate,std::allocator< Rate > > const &,DayCounter const &,Schedule const &,Real,Period const &,Calendar const &,BusinessDayConvention const)
    ConvertibleFixedCouponBond::ConvertibleFixedCouponBond(ext::shared_ptr< Exercise > const &,Real,std::vector< ext::shared_ptr< Callability >,std::allocator< ext::shared_ptr< Callability > > > const &,Date const &,Integer,std::vector< Rate,std::allocator< Rate > > const &,DayCounter const &,Schedule const &,Real,Period const &,Calendar const &)
    ConvertibleFixedCouponBond::ConvertibleFixedCouponBond(ext::shared_ptr< Exercise > const &,Real,std::vector< ext::shared_ptr< Callability >,std::allocator< ext::shared_ptr< Callability > > > const &,Date const &,Integer,std::vector< Rate,std::allocator< Rate > > const &,DayCounter const &,Schedule const &,Real,Period const &)
    ConvertibleFixedCouponBond::ConvertibleFixedCouponBond(ext::shared_ptr< Exercise > const &,Real,std::vector< ext::shared_ptr< Callability >,std::allocator< ext::shared_ptr< Callability > > > const &,Date const &,Integer,std::vector< Rate,std::allocator< Rate > > const &,DayCounter const &,Schedule const &,Real)
    ConvertibleFixedCouponBond::ConvertibleFixedCouponBond(ext::shared_ptr< Exercise > const &,Real,std::vector< ext::shared_ptr< Callability >,std::allocator< ext::shared_ptr< Callability > > > const &,Date const &,Integer,std::vector< Rate,std::allocator< Rate > > const &,DayCounter const &,Schedule const &)
```

I really need this to be done, so I am looking for anyone who could help me
Is this probelm simply because the python version of quantlib is not fully updated with `CallabilityPrice` turned into `BondPrice` and other functions remain the same?

Answer (score 0):

In recent versions of QuantLib, a couple of arguments (the dividends and the credit spread) were moved from the bond to the engine.  I'm afraid I have no example in Python, but the C++ version includes [an example](https://github.com/lballabio/QuantLib/blob/master/Examples/ConvertibleBonds/ConvertibleBonds.cpp#L204) you can check.

Comment: Thank you! Now I could get my code running, but I find that with all parameters identical, code from [link](http://gouthamanbalaraman.com/blog/value-convertible-bond-quantlib-python.html) returns NPV of 132.3 while the new quantlib arguments with dividend and credit spread removed from bond to engine returns 136.1. Is this 3.8% of difference from difference in arguments handling so I could ignore, or there may be some other issue with my settings? Thank you so much by the way

Comment: I'm still getting 132.3 with QuantLib 1.26 and Goutham's code.  Are you sure you didn't change anything else?

Comment: Thanks! I forgot to add dividend to the pricing engine, thank you now I get NPV of 132.3.
For other user, the change should be as following:
`ql.ConvertibleFixedCouponBond(exercise, conversion_ratio, callability_schedule, issue_date, settlement_days, [coupon], day_count, schedule, redemption)`
`ql.BinomialConvertibleEngine(bsm_process, "crr", time_steps, credit_spread_handle, dividend_schedule)`